# CActiveDataProvider With Custom Sql

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to create a custom query for my $dataprovider

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_name';
$dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql);
```

I'm using CSqlDataProvider which works fine, however is it possible to return the data as model object rather than a row array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it such way. [Read more about CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider)

If you want to get array of ActiveRecord objects you need to use `ARModel::model()->findAll()` method.

[Read more about static method model() of CActiveRecord class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#model-detail)

[Read more about method findAll() of CActiveRecord class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/#findAll-detail)

Comment: new to Yii. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: if you are only starting of studiing Yii -- may be the better way will be to study Yii2, it is already in RC stage (they promise stable release this week).

The working with database in Yii2 more better and more easy.

Comment: Yes it is. And there is a lot of other feautures in Yii2.
As for me -- Yii2 seems to be more powerful and more _easy_ to study.